# imagecolorallocatealpha returns white image

Tags: php, png, transparency, gd

I have a problem with the imagecolorallocatealpha in PHP. When setting the opacity to 127, I get a white image instead of a transparent one.

Here is my code

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $color);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
exit;
```

I have also tried this one but I get the same result

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$x = imagecolorat($image, 0,0);
imagecolortransparent($image, $x);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
exit;
```

Any idea ? Can it be related to server configuration ?

Comment: Your code (first example) works for me. I know the question is ridiculous, but are you sure you're not overlaying the image over a white background? Because when viewed directly in a browser, or over a white background, it's natural for the image to appear white, because you can see the white behind it. I'm only asking this because your example works perfectly for me. Here is how the image looks when viewed in the network tab of Google Chrome's dev tools: http://i.imgur.com/rohsM.png

Comment: Unfortunately, it is white, it's not the background (in firefox, it's pretty obvious given that the image background is some kind of dark grey). However, when viewed in the network tab of Google Chrome's dev tools, it looks strange, as if it had not been interpreted as a png. http://d.pr/i/1Fte (I test it with a php file that contains only the code above).

Answer (score 1):

Replace the first line

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
```

with

```
$image = imagecreate($width, $height);
```

Transparancy should now work, but the colour palet won't show some true colours corectely.

Any white pixels will now be transparant.

To change the transparancy colour from white, use:

```
$r = *red colour value (0 to 255)*;
$g = *green colour value (0 to 255)*;
$b = *blue colour value (0 to 255)*;
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, $r, $g, $b, 127);
```

Answer (score -1):

If that's **all** the code you are using for the image file, you haven't defined any values for the `$width` and `$height` variables, and the script throws an error.

As a general rule, when you want to debug an image, remove the Content-Type header. That way, you can view any potential errors by accessing the script in a browser.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it, I also added values for dmentions. So the exact code is
    <?php

        $width = 300;
        $height = 300;
        $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagesavealpha($image, true);
        $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagefill($image, 0, 0, $color);
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        header('Content-Disposition: filename="thisisatest.png"');
        imagepng($image);
        imagedestroy($image);
        exit;
Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Strange. Could you post the phpinfo() section that tells you about your GD library version? Mine looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/So5QC.png

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu, I seem to remember something about having to manually compile PHP to use the bundled GD library instead of the official one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/74647